# How to use ssh to fake ip to load website

Tags: c#, ssh

I am trying to build an application. How to use ssh to fake ip and use ip ssh to load website if use WebRequest to check ip it will show ip of ssh

I find can use [SSH.NET Library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/), but i don't know how to use it. Any one help me example code to use it.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What do you mean by Port Forwarding ? Are you talking about forwarding incoming connections through NAT? Why would anyone use SSH to load a website? SSH is terminal protocol, am I missing anything here?

Comment: @fahadash: i use ssh as proxy and load website with ip of ssh